# gradle 1.6 to 1.11 migration error

Tags: java, gradle, testng, build.gradle

I have a functional test module that uses TestNG and has a gradle build script that works just fine in gradle 1.6, I was trying to bump up my gradle version to 1.11 and this module started throwing the following error.

```
Could not find property 'projectDir' on   org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions_Decorated@47537eb5.
```

The error is on the following gradle task

```
task adminTest(type: Test) {
  useTestNG() {
    systemProperties['browser'] = 'firefox'
    systemProperties['dbUrl'] = connectionString
    systemProperties['baseurl'] = "$baseurl"

    suites 'src/test/java/org/open/functional/testng-admin.xml'
  }
   options {
      listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
      listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
   }
   workingDir = 'build/'
}
```

I couldn't find any indication if this is a known issue. Is there is any change I should make to the gradle script to make gradle 1.11 run my TestNG scripts?

Comment: It turns out that this problem only happens when using gradle version 1.11, I bumped up my project to gradle 1.9 (which is also supported by IntelliJ Idea  V13) and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a known bug - check out this known issue in the [Gradle 1.11 release notes](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.11/release-notes). See [GRADLE-3020](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3020).

Changing the `suites` option like so should allow it to work with 1.11:

```
suites file('src/test/java/org/open/functional/testng-admin.xml')
```